# PHP: htmlspecialchars_decode with double quotes won't work

Tags: php

i have encoded text with html elements.
In this text i have single quotes and double quotes.

By PHP manual htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES) should decode all quotes.
Double quotes have "034" code, but this now work.

My code:

```
$new = htmlspecialchars_decode('&lt;a href=&#034;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;', ENT_QUOTES);

var_dump($new);
```

Result: `string '<a href=&#034;test'>Test</a>' (length=28)`

Why i get "`&#034;`" ? It should be double quotes

Comment: works fine for me(http://codepad.viper-7.com/Rkc6ZA -- need to view frame source)  - sure its not double encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars_decode` seems to work a little differently on older versions. Try html_entity_decode instead:

`$new = html_entity_decode('&lt;a href=&#034;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;', ENT_QUOTES);`